# Playing lots of audio files crashes React Native app on some iOS devices

Tags: react-native, crash

I am creating an app that has several categories of small audio clips. When the user clicks on a category it loads a list of audio files. When a user clicks on an audio file it plays the audio.

I have several people testing my app on iOS. It does not crash for me, but other people are reporting it crashes after going through several audio files. It is not specific audio files that it crashing on and seems rather intermittent. I am using `willBlurSubscription` to release the memory.

Here is a simplified version of my code for the audio list:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

var Sound = require('react-native-sound');
Sound.setCategory("Playback"); //Needed for audio to play on IOS devices

import {
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

import files from '../assets/json/files';

export default class AudioList extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        
    }

    playAudio = (file) => {
        console.log(file)

               if (this.sound) {
            console.log("SOUND")
                        
                        try {   
                                this.sound.release()
                        } catch(error){
                console.log("A sound release error has occured 111")
            }
                        finally {
                                this.sound = null
                        }
                }

                this.sound  = new Sound('audio/' + file, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
                        if (error) {
                                console.log('error', error);
                                this.sound = null;
                        } else {
                                this.sound.play(()=> {
                                        try {   
                                                if (this.sound){
                                                        this.sound.release()
                                                }
                                        } catch(error) {
                        console.log("A sound release error has occured 222")
                    }
                                        finally {
                                                this.sound = null
                                        }
                                })
                        }
                })


                this.willBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
                        'blur',
                        () => {
                                try {
                                        if (this.sound){
                                                this.sound.release()
                                        }
                                } catch(error) {
                    console.log("A sound release error has occured 333")
                }
                                finally {
                                        this.sound = null
                                }

                        }
                )



    }

  componentWillUnmount() {

        try {
                this.willBlurSubscription &&
                this.willBlurSubscription.remove &&
                this.willBlurSubscription.remove()
        } catch(error) {}
        finally {
                this.willBlurSubscription = null
        }
  }

  
  render() {
    let list = files[this.props.route.params['category_id']]

    let audio_list = list.data.map((item, index) => {
        return <View key={index}>
            {!!item.audio && 
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
                    {item.audio ? 
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.playAudio(item.audio)}>
                            <Image source={require('../assets/images/play_button.png')} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        :
                        <View></View>
                    }
                    <Text>{item.text}</Text>
                </View>
            {!!item.audio2 &&
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
                    {item.audio2 ?
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.playAudio(item.audio2)}>
                            <Image source={require('../assets/images/play_button.png')} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        :
                        <View></View>
                    }
                    <Text>{item.text2}</Text>
                </View>
            }

            
        </View>
    })



    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View>
                {audio_list}
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )

    

  }  
}
```

**Sentry Report:**

I have now implemented Sentry and on crash I am getting the following in Sentry:

```
RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a.sound.play')
```

Please remember that this is an intermittent problem. The sound file does indeed exist so should not be null. Other times I click on it it does play the file.

I am wondering if the clearing of the previous audio file to load the new one is causing the problem. During that short time it could be null.

The reason for clearing the previous audio file was to eliminate memory leaks of creating so many audio objects.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried adding `null check ?`, null is not an object generally comes when your sound variable is null, thus sound.play throws error. `this.sound?.play`, because even if you are saying that sound file does exist, there maybe some edge case where it turns out to be null.

Comment: @AkshayShenoy Yes, that is something I will be doing. However, I do not understand why it is showing null intermittently for files that do actually exist. If I just have a check for null, if the user tries to play the clip it won't play for them even if it's there.

Comment: Can you just show the files(sound mp3 files) which you have stored in both android and ios folders. There must be something wrong there thus some file is being null, since there are some rules of how and where these files must be placed. Also there is a good chance that since your are deleting the previous audio file might be causing null for a short time, and null check can be enough to handle it.

Comment: @AkshayShenoy It has nothing to do with the files stored in the directory. They are guaranteed to be there. They do play most of the time, but every once in a while they show up as null. And yes, I do believe it has to do with deleting the previous audio object os is null for a short time. In this case, I could do a null check, however, that will cause the audio not to play when it should be playing.

Answer (score 0):

it is happening because you are using `willBlurSubscription` method, when you go to another screen and come back to the screen then sometimes this glitch is occurring

**Simple solution is to play sound safe by checking sound instance before play** like this

```
this.sound && this.sound.play(()=> {
```

I think, you should use `navigation.addListener('focus'` to reinitialize sound object to prevent this crash.

Comment: This will end up preventing the audio from playing though, even if it is there. Also, it does not seem to be only when leaving screen and coming back. There are many audio files on the same screen. Sometimes the first several will play and then suddenly one will decide not to play.

Comment: @kojow7 I think, you should use `navigation.addListener('focus'` to reinitialize sound object to prevent this crash.

Comment: I'm not sure how using navigation would work as I'm not often navigating off of the scene when this happens. Each screen has several audio clips. The issue usually happens when going through several of these audio clips in the same scene, so no navigation is being done.

Comment: `evaluating 'a.sound.play'` you can see in the error log, it only happens when you try to call the play function on that time sound object makes empty. I think, it also can b reproduce if the user opens many sounds fastly.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Because they are very small audio clips (often a single word), the user can go through them quickly. Would there be a better way to write the code so this is not an issue?